# Periodic to incremental (data reduction)

Tags: matlab, increment, reduction, periodic-processing

It's some time I was thinking about solving this problem. I have a registration of angular data (Angle(~20000,1)) variating between 0 and 355 (a potentiometer attached to a rotary testing machine), and I wanted to convert it in an incremental form, since I want the final total angular displacement. The main issue is that between 355 and the next 0 there are no jumps but a fast decrement (with strongly negative slope in time vs angle space). I've tried 2 ways up to now:

1. Calculate the `Angslope=diff(Angle)`, extract with find the indexes `j1=find(Angslope>0.2 & Angslope<0.2)` to avoid the negative slopes due to the inversion of angular signal, then try to apply those indexes to the original `Angle(n,1)`, as `Angle2=Angle(j1)`. The trouble is the n-1 length of Angslope and the fact that somehow there is not a simple shift of my indexes of one position.
2. For cycles and logical, wanting to exclude data if the previous one is < the current value,etc

   ```
   Angle2=zeros(size(Angle,1),1);

   for i=2:size(Angle,1) 
      if Angle(i,1)<Angle(i-1,1) 
      Angle2(i,1)=NaN;
      else    Angle2(i,1)=Angle(i,1);
      end
   end
   ```

Which works good, but I don't know how to "match up" the single increment steps I obtain!

Any help or simple comment would be of great help!!

Comment: Could you upload a  `plot(Angle)` somewhere?

Comment: Here's the Time vs Angle plot (.fig) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72363476/angle.fig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `unwrap` function. For this you have to convert your angles into radians, but that's not a big deal.

You can get the increments in one line:

```
Inc = diff(unwrap(Angle*pi/180))*180/pi;
```

and your total angular displacement:

```
Tot = sum(Inc);
```

Best,

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `unwrap`!

Comment: Did you mean `cumsum`?

Comment: Well, both sum and cumsum can be used, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Oh! I see we don't need the `diff` and `cumsum` then! In this case I even think *BasSwinckels*' answer is what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but probably I have mispoken the starting data:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72363476/angle.fig When I use diff and unwrap as you told me, the total displacement is strongly affected by the angle inversion between a 355 and the next 0, thus I've got a strongly negative cumulative angle ~-60

Comment: @Aretu: I don't get it. The proposed solution works for me. (loose the `sum` and `diff`) What's the problem?

Comment: Thank you for making me know about the unwrap, I solved it with Angle2 from the for cycle and then unwrapping it!